# Linking or Routing dynamicaly with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, next.js

I am trying to find the best way to link to a details page from a list of objects that are mapped. The list fetches items from an API and works fine. The problem is that I cant pass the id to my details page and get this error when I click on the objects.

> :3000/_next/static/development/pages/_app.js?ts=1592696161086:1299 GET http://localhost:3000/flowers/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

and in the url `http://localhost:3000/flowers/[object%20Object]`

This is what I have in my /pages/flowers.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Link from 'next/link'
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css'

export default function Flowers() {
  const LISTURL = 'https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers.json'
  const TESTURL = 'https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers/9.json' 
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(LISTURL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setItems(json))
  }, [] )
  
  return (
    <Layout>
        <Head>
        <title></title>
      </Head>
      <section className={utilStyles.centerSection}>
      <button>Shade loving plants</button>
      <button>Sun loving plants</button>
      </section>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ul key={item._id.oid}>
          <li className={utilStyles.listItem}>
          <Link href='/flowers/[flowerid]' as={`/flowers/${item._id}`}>

            <a className={utilStyles.list}>
              <h2 className={utilStyles.headingTop}>{item.common_name}</h2>
             <img  className={utilStyles.imgList} src={`${item.cover_image}`} alt={item.common_name} />
            </a>
           </Link> 
          </li>  
        </ul>
      ))
      }
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

This is pages/[flowerid].js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Router from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css'

const FlowerDetail = () => {
  const [flower, setFlower] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
     const { flowerId } = Router.query

      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers/${flowerId}.json`
        )
        console.log(`blomma`, data)
        setFlower(data)

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Can not find id`, error)
      }
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])

  if (!flower) return <div>Loading...</div>
  console.log('no flowers to see')

  return (
  <Layout>
    <Head>
        <title></title>
    </Head>
    <div>
      <p>Blooming season {flower.blooming_season}</p>
      <img  className={utilStyles.imgList} src={`${flower.cover_image}`} alt={flower.common_name} />
      <p>Common name {flower.common_name}</p>
      <h5>{flower.notes}</h5>
    </div>
  </Layout>
  )
}

export default FlowerDetail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problems holding you back...

The `_id` coming from your [API](https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers.json) is an object which contains an `oid` property:

```
 "_id": {
   "oid": "5e57880c9fa50a095f475c18"
 },
```

Therefore you'll want to use the `items._id.oid` property as a link source. As is, you're passing the `id` *object* to the link source, which is why your links are **invalid**: `http://localhost:3000/flowers/[object%20Object]`

Unfortunately, that's not the only problem. The other problem is that the current data structure doesn't contain any reference to the URL parameter id (where `1.json` is supposed to reference `oid: 5e579cdfe99bdd0ca1cf64a3`, `2.json` references `oid: 5e579dfcb664120cd14b4331`, and so on), so you'll need to reconfigure your API data to include a property with this URL `id` within each data document (`id: 1`, `id: 2`, ...etc) and then use that `id` as your link source OR you'll have to reconfigure your API to utilize this `oid` property as a URL parameter to match against (instead of `1.json` it'll use the `oid` as a URL parameter to match against and be `5e579cdfe99bdd0ca1cf64a3.json`).

For example, this [API endpoint](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/9) (which comes from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) contains an `id` property that is used as a URL parameter to retrieve the specific JSON file by its `id` (notice how **both** the **URL** and the **JSON data** contain an `id` of `9`).

On a side note, if you're using Chrome, you can install this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh) to prettify/format `JSON`, so it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QE3m.png).

---

### OID doesn't match the requested API endpoint

For reference, here's how your response is currently structured when you query this [endpoint](https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers/9.json) (notice that the `9` in `https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers/9.json` isn't referenced/used anywhere within the JSON data, so using the `oid` (`https://flowers-mock-data.firebaseio.com/flowers/5e57a0e1e5f2470d789335c2.json`) as a parameter won't be valid):

```
{
  "__v": {
    "numberInt": "0"
  },
  "_id": {
    "oid": "5e57a0e1e5f2470d789335c2"
  },
  "blooming_season": "Late Spring",
  "common_name": "Ornamental onion",
  "cover_image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565685225009-fc85d9109c80?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80",
  "depth": {
    "numberInt": "3"
  },
  "height": [
    {
      "numberInt": "6"
    },
    {
      "numberInt": "60"
    }
  ],
  "latin_name": "Allium",
  "notes": "Usually pest-free; a great cut flower",
  "soil": [
    "well drained",
    "moist",
    "fertile"
  ],
  "spacing": {
    "numberInt": "12"
  },
  "sun": true
}
```

---

### Example fetch data repo

I've put together an example with some comments that incorporates the API endpoint (jsonplaceholder) mentioned in the paragraph above, as well as implementing some of nextjs's [data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) methods (excluded `getStaticPaths` for simplicity; however, technically, it can replace `getServerSideProps` in the dynamic [pages/users/[id].js](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-basic-data-fetch/blob/master/pages/users/%5Bid%5D.js#L50-L68) page since the data will never be changed/updated during runtime):

[fetch data example repo](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-basic-data-fetch)